# Angular SCSS - @extend scope

Tags: angular, sass, scope, extend

The class `.testt` in the global style sheet:

```
.testt{
  color: red;
}
```

**Including (`@extend`) that class into another class of a component A is not working**

> compA.scss

```
.compA__body {
    @extend .testt;
}
```

> Error:

```
SassError: The target selector was not found.
Use "@extend .center !optional" to avoid this error.
   ╷
32 │     @extend .center;
   │     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
```

How to fix this scope issue ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `@import 'path/to/global/stylesheet';` to have access to the classes in there, This will however add those classes into your component style sheet too.

The best solution would be to have a partial scss file which contains the properties you want to extend as a [placeholder selector](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend#placeholder-selectors), this way you are only importing scss that will not compile into classes itself, and you will be free to extend them in your components.

**_extends.scss**

```
%test {
  color: red;
}
```

**component.styles.scss**

```
@import 'path/to/_extends.scss';

.compA__body {
    @extend %test;
}
```